# elasticsearch upsert without document id

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I query my index to find a document. If I find a document I know the _id value to update else I don't have _id value.

Using the upsert below, I can update when I have _id. If I dont have _id how can I have elasticsearch to provide one and insert a new document?

Purpose: I dont want to have 2 functions, one to create a new doc and another to update it...

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/{value_of_id}/_update' -d '{
  "doc" : {
      "name" : "new_name"
  },
  "doc_as_upsert" : true
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Something like "update by query"?

See here:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2230

for the original issue/proposal, some experimental work toward implementation, discussion about the pros and cons of including, and a link to the plug-in that was developed to support the behavior.