# Elasticsearch upsert based on query

Tags: elasticsearch

Two years ago someone asked [how to do upserts when you don't know a document's id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525199/elasticsearch-upsert-without-document-id). The (unaccepted) answer referenced the [feature request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2230)
that resulted in the [`_update_by_query` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

However `_update_by_query` does not allow insertion if no hits exist, so it is not really an upsert, but just another way to do update.

Is there a way to do an upsert without an `_id` yet? I know that my query will always return one or zero results. Or am I forced to do multiple requests (and maintain the uniqueness myself)?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible right now. `_update` provides an `upsert` attribute, but this doesn't work with `_update_by_query` unfortunately. The following just gives you an error around `Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [upsert].`

```
POST website/doc/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "url": "http://foo.com"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.views+=1",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
   "upsert": {
       "views": 1,
       "url": "http://foo.com"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing `in_stock` values in all the document now you can reduce its count by 1:

```json
POST products/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.in_stock--"
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, welcome to Stackoverflow! I am aware of the `_update_by_query` API and that it can use scripting to modify documents without retrieving them, my question is whether there is a way to do upserts in this way, i.e. do an update if a match exists and otherwise do an insert. Your sample does not allow me to do insert if no documents match.